# Sysprep ping and keeping all settings the same

Tags: virtual-machine, sysprep, answerfile

I am creating a VM image which will be deployed to hundreds of hyper-v-hypervisors across the country on different locations/stores.
I already customized the VM as I want it to be including customizations on user profiles etc…

I now basically want to keep all my customizations after sysprepping the VM. All location specific configuration will be done by a PowerShell script executed via the answer file.

My problem now, that I am loosing customizations on the user accounts i created. (i.e.: shortcuts on the local admin account for the help desk, Group Policy Object (GPO) for another local user (completely locked down account))… hHowever this stuff gets reset after Sysprep.

I have already check the Sysprep documentation, but this whole topic is very complicated (at least for me).

Does anybody has an idea if there is some setting where I can keep those customizations?